# IE / WAMPServer / Multiple Virtutal Hosts - Only one virtual host properly allows logging in and preserving session?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, wampserver

I have a strange problem with multiple virtual hosts in WampServer / PHP.  I have two folders in my web directory and two virtual hosts each pointing to the folder.  When I try to log in to my application (ActionAIM), I am able to log in and see the session variable populated on the screen.  When I try to log into ActionAIM_Demo, I can login but when I redirect from my authenticate script to index.php (my landing page), I see no session variable values present.

Is there something wrong with IE, as this works in FireFox?
How do I resolve this issue?

**Apache Config Snippet (Virtual Hosts Definition)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ActionAIM"
    ServerName ActionAIM
    ServerAlias ActionAIM
    ErrorLog "logs/aim-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/aim-access.log" common
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/ActionAIM">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ActionAIM_Demo"
    ServerName ActionAIM_Demo
    ServerAlias ActionAIM_Demo
    ErrorLog "logs/aimdemo-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/aimdemo-access.log" common
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/ActionAIM_Demo">
          AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**authenticate.php**

```
<?php
        require_once('session.php');
        require_once('usermanager.php');

        $username = isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username'] : '';
        $password = isset($_POST['password'])? $_POST['password'] : '';


        if ($username == '' or $password == '')
        {
                header('Location: login.php?err=1');    
                return;
        }

        $userManager = new UserManager($username, $password);
        if (!$userManager->isValidUserName($username))
        {
                header('Location: login.php?err=2');
                return;
        }
        else
        {
                $confirmed = $userManager->confirmUserNamePassword($username, $password);
                if (!$confirmed)
                {     
                    header('Location: login.php?err=3');    
                    return;                     
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userManager->getUserID($username, $password);
                    $_SESSION['userrole'] = $userManager->getUserRole($username, $password);
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true; 
                    $_SESSION['lastnamefirstname'] = $userManager->getLastNameFirstName($username, $password); 
                    header('Location: index.php');
                    exit;
                }
        }

?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php                                                  
    session_cache_limiter ('private, must-revalidate');
    session_start();
?>
```

Comment: Show how you redirect from auth script to index.php, on the site that you have a problem with

Comment: Please see edited question.  I have included the authenticate script where I redirect.

Comment: I assume `session.php` does a `start_session()`? And we all know that assumption is the mother of all screwups

Comment: Yes, I did post the session.php just now as I forgot to include it in the original re-post.

Comment: From the manual: __In private mode, the Expire header sent to the client may cause confusion for some browsers__ Try removing the `session_cache_limiter ('private, must-revalidate');` and see if it starts to work and then work out why you thought that was required

Comment: I did remove session_cache_limiter but it did not have an effect for ActionAIM_Demo.  I included the mentioned instruction session_cache_limiter because I kept getting page expired when I press the back button on both IE and Firefox.